# Double click image function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

can someone help me in creating a simple script, that when somebody double click the picture, the button {LikeButton color="grey"} will be activated then a heart picture will fade.

Here's my photo block section code:

```
{block:Photo}<div class="containerimg">

                <span class="font-a"><a href="{Permalink}">{block:Date} {Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year}{/block:Date}</a><br/><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a><br/>{block:HasTags} {block:Tags} <a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags} {/block:HasTags}</span>

                    <div class="post photo">
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>

                        {block:Caption}
                            <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                        {/block:Caption}


                    </div>

                    <div class="status">
                    {block:RebloggedFrom} 
                    <img src="{ReblogParentPortraitURL-24}" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);" /> <a href="{ReblogParentURL}" style="position: absolute; padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px;">{ReblogParentName}</a>
                    {/block:RebloggedFrom}
                    {block:NotReblog} 
                    <img src="{PortraitURL-24}" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);" /> <a href="{Permalink}" style="position: absolute; padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px;">{Name}</a>
                    {/block:NotReblog}

                    <div class="reblogg">
                    {LikeButton color="grey"}&nbsp;&nbsp;{ReblogButton color="grey"}
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>

                {/block:Photo}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [`dblclick`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').dblclick(function(){
        // do something
        alert('Picture fade out...')
        $(this).fadeOut().slow();
    });
});
```

[You can try it here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YXrS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $('#yourPictureID').dblclick(function{ 
   $('#LikeButtonID').attr("disable","false");
   $('#heartPictureID').css("opacity","1");
 });
```